# Soap Message to Java Object

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap

```xml
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:wsa=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing\" xmlns:cs=\"urn:CardServices\" xmlns:ebppif1=\"urn:PaymentServer\" xmlns:el=\"urn:ExtListsServices\" xmlns:iiacs=\"urn:IIACardServices\" xmlns:lm=\"urn:Limits\">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring></faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ebppif1:PaymentServerException>
                    <provider>RSW</provider>
                    <error>129</error>
                    <description>201433</description>
                    <screen>RSW129</screen>
                </ebppif1:PaymentServerException>
            </detail>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How to create java object using @XmlRootElement,@XmlElement.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Fault", namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
@Data
public class FaultDto {
    @XmlElement(name = "faultcode")
    private String faultCode;
    @XmlElement(name = "detail")
    private DetailDto detail;
}
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "detail")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DetailDto {
    @XmlElement(name = "PaymentServerException")
    private PaymentExcepDto excepDto;
}
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "PaymentServerException")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PaymentExcepDto {

    @XmlElement(name = "provider")
    protected String provider;
    @XmlElement(name = "error")
    protected String error;
    //others

}
```

I am getting this result :  FaultDto(faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client, detail=DetailDto(excepDto=null))
How to catch PaymentServerException ?

Comment: The XML as posted is invalid as it contains backslashes where they don't belong in XML.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I found my mistake. Now I can fetch PaymentServerException